# How to set budget unit which through call API's code

Tags: facebook, curl, currency, facebook-ads-api

Maybe my ad account's pay method was set **CNY**.

How to set budget unit which through call API's code?

Here is my CURL code.
[create ad set by CURL](https://gist.github.com/freedom-diy/eec21251b4123797c4a2)

**Error msg**:
Your budget is too low. The minimum budget for this ad set is $1.00.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign) related to bidding

> The bid amount's unit is cent for currencies like USD, EUR, and the basic unit for currencies like JPY, KRW.

In your call you use `bid_amount=1, daily_budget=3`, **which means 1 and 3 cents**. For `bid_amount` that may be relevant amount (depends on used `billing_event`), but for budget it's too low.

You can see minimum budget values for different currencies in [budget limits docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/budget-limits/v2.5).

Also note that not all currencies use the same offset, which means not everywhere 1 means 1 cent. Those offsets are documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/currencies).

Comment: When I use `daily_budget=100 `, the call is go to next step. In addition, How to know the **currency** for currently ad set through any search call?

Comment: The currency is always the same for the whole account. You can get it from Graph API using `/v2.5/act_<your_account_id>?fields=currency`